# How to display symbols "&" and "=" in url?

Tags: php, url, encode, symbols

I want to add symbols "&" and "=" to the value of the option,
but output always return %26 and %3d. How can I decode than value?

```
<option class="low-high" value="<?php $encoded='price%26product_list_dir%3Dasc';
echo rawurldecode($encoded);?>">
```

Output return price%26product_list_dir=asc but I want 
    price&product_list_dir=asc

Comment: You mean when you submit the form, or in the source? Why write them as that if you want them to be the actual character? Comes out as literal characters for me https://3v4l.org/o2QH0. `=` and `&` have special context in GET requests though. For them to be processed correctly you want them to process as the encoded values

Comment: putting your code in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and executing it resolves to `price&product_list_dir=asc` so that works just fine and if it doesn't work fine for you you're going to have to add more details on how you're actually testing. You want `urldecode` rather than `rawurldecode` (because why would you except the `+`?) but this code works fine.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @user3783243 I use this code in Magento 2 in sort by price (low to high) option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this script and now it's working. Thank you all for help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var url = $(this).val();
    if (url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
    return false;
 });
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the part of the string with the correct symbols

```
$str = "price%26product_list_dir%3Dasc";
$keywords = array("%26", "%3D");
$replacement = array("&", "=");

$res = str_replace($keywords, $replacement, $str);
```